# jquery to apply css style

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table whose td values are displayed as

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><?=$something?></td>
<td><?=$something?></td>
<td><?=$something?></td>
<td><?=$something?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><?=$somethingelse?></td>
<td><?=$somethingelse?></td>
<td><?=$somethingelse?></td>
<td><?=$somethingelse?></td>

</tr>
```

I would like to apply jquery for all td in the second row after some condition is met, for example, the first somethingelse in the first td is smaller than zero.

Comment: Where this `<?=` server tag ends?

Comment: So what problem are you having? Selecting the cells in the second row? Finding the cells you are about in the first row? Getting the content of those cells? Performing the comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
if(yourCondition) {
 $('table > tbody > tr:eq(2) > td').each(function() {
   $(this).css("color", "red"); //add color red for example
 });
}
```

Do you mean something like that..

Comment: @JohnSmith This is the direct ancestor selector ... meaning you select the td that is directly within tr in the DOM

Comment: @john what about the conditions you have mentioned about ??? is that fullfilled in this answer ???

Answer (score 0):

`$('tr:nth-child(2) td')` this will select tds of 2nd row

Answer (score 0):

This will do it for you.

```
//get the second table row (eq is zero-indexed)
var second_tr = $('tr').eq(1);
//get the contents of the first element in second row
var first_td_val = second_tr.find('td:first').text();​
if(first_td_val < 0){
    //do something with the second table row.
    second_tr.css('background-color', '#bada55');
}
​
```

See [This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DzLuj/)